# Java.lang.ClassnotfoundException com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I am getting a `java.lang.ClassnotFoundException` while running this program:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class MysqlCon{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo","root","root");
            //here sonoo is the database name, root is the username and root is the password
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");

            while(rs.next())
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));

            con.close();

        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}

    }
}
```

SQl Code:

```
create database sonoo;  
use sonoo;  
create table emp(id int(10),name varchar(40),age int(3));
```

I also set the classpath to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\mysql-5.0.7.jar then also its giving an same error.

I think the code is perfectly fine and there is wrong something with `mysql.jar` file. Also I downloaded this jar file from the following website: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysql507jar.html and I'm using Mysql 5.6 server.

Comment: How are you running this? What do you mean by by "set the classpath"?

Comment: Why you don't use the official JDBC - driver for Mysql? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: And: Because this is a system library which you propabily be using a lot , why don't you just add it to your IDE configuration? You won't even have to care too much about classpaths, because your IDE will configure the build path automatically.

Comment: donwload the jar file from
[link]http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: Seriously: what article or book is telling people to put the jar in the lib/ext folder? And then tell people to also manually put that folder on the classpath?? This is far from the first time I see this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try surrounding this in parentheses, it might help.
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\mysql-5.0.7.jar"

2) Also, open the JAR (with some program able 
to open ZIP files) and make sure the class is in 
there (under the right package/directory structure).

The error definitely means the class is not on 
the classpath at runtime even though you think it is.